# Pentaho PDI SCD Type 2 Inserts new row when data has not changed

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, scd2

I'm starting to use Pentaho PDI Version 9.3 for experimenting with Type 2 SCD. But when I run the same transformation 2 times, with the same data (no change in data), a new `version` of each row gets inserted every time, even though the row data has not changed. This is my setup:

Overall view:
[image]

**Dimension Lookup/Update Setup - Keys**
[image]

**Dimension Lookup/Update Setup - Fields**
[image]

**Expected outcome**
No matter how many times I run this, if the values of `exercise` and `short_name` have not changed, no new rows should be added. But when I

**Actual outcome**
A new version of each and every record is created each time I run the transformation, even when the `exercise` and `short_name` fields have not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue recently, and we eventually tracked the source to the fact one of the columns in the source table (queried by a `Table Input` step like yours) had a different data type than the corresponding column in the target table (also updated by a `Dimension Lookup/Update` step like yours).
(It could also be you're casting the values in your `Select values` step, which I imagine causes the same behaviour.)